# how to retrieve data from sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am working on an sqlite database in which I am sure that I have inserted in sqlite correctly.
Now i am fetching data from sqlite using cursor but when I set the data to Texview, my application crashes. Here is my table:

Here is my cursor code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " where id = 23";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
```

And here is my code in activity from where i am fetching data from database

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    Cursor c = dbHelper.getCheckOutProduct();
    if (c != null){
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            int Id = c.getInt(0);
            int paymentTypeID = c.getInt(1);
            int customerID = c.getInt(2);
         }
        }
```

Where am I making a mistake? Thank-you in advance
[here is my exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glWQd.png)

Comment: Please add the error and the logcat to the question.

Comment: exception in logcat become disappears immediately in logcat . i am not showing exception

Comment: choose the dead process in from Logcat window and copy the error message

Comment: please see it is it correct: String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_TABLE + " WHERE ID = "+ autoOrderId; Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

Answer (score 1):

Your Isuue is that you have selected all column by

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_TABLE + " ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ";
```

But you didnt get column index  for **AddressId** column

Change

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
Cursor c = dbHelper.getCheckOutRequest();
if (c != null){
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        int Id = c.getInt(0);
        int paymentTypeID = c.getInt(1);
        int customerID = c.getInt(2);
     }
    }
```

To

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
Cursor c = dbHelper.getCheckOutRequest();
if (c != null){
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        int Id = c.getInt(0);
        int AddressID = c.getInt(1);
        int paymentTypeID = c.getInt(2);
        int customerID = c.getInt(3);
     }
    }
```

Comment: i have done i now. i got another exception see my updated question

Comment: You need to use movetoFirst() @ansar abbas

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are casting a `String` to `int`, try this -

```
int Id = 0;
int paymentTypeID = 0;
int customerID = 0;

dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    Cursor c = dbHelper.getCheckOutRequest();
    if (c != null){
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
             Id = c.getInt(0);
             paymentTypeID = c.getInt(1);
             customerID = c.getInt(2);
     }
        }
```

Then in Textview,

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(Id));
```

Comment: data type of column is in integer type

Comment: @ansarabbas updated answer, in the meantime, show the logcat

Comment: please see it is it correct: String query = "SELECT * FROM " + ORDER_TABLE + " WHERE ID = "+ autoOrderId;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

Comment: i have done i now. i got another exception see  y updated question

Answer (score 0):

let's change your cursor way and take it in some othe code way
you have this tabel and you wanna set and get the data from it hmm lets try harder code 
but it gonna be easy with use it up next

```
||========================================||
|| ORDER_TABLE                            ||
||========================================||
||  ID                                    ||
||  AddressID                             ||
||  PaymentTypeID                         ||
||  CustomerID                            ||
||========================================||
```

put this function in DBHelper class

```
public ArrayList<Map<String, String>> getorder()
{
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery("select * from " + ORDER_TABLE + " ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 " , null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
        datanum.put("ID", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        datanum.put("AddressID", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("AddressID")));
        datanum.put("PaymentTypeID", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("PaymentTypeID")));
        datanum.put("CustomerID", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("CustomerID")));
        array_list.add(datanum);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

and this code to fetching data from DBHelper

```
    DB = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> order = DB.getorder();


  String ID;
  String AddressID;
  String PaymentTypeID;
  String CustomerID;

    try {
    if(order.size() = 0){
        //database is empty
    } else {
         ID            = order.get(0).get("ID");
         AddressID     = order.get(0).get("AddressID");
         PaymentTypeID = order.get(0).get("PaymentTypeID");
         CustomerID    = order.get(0).get("CustomerID");
    }
  }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    Toast.makeText(this,"ERROR IndexOutOfBoundsException :. "+ e ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

and if you have alot of orders

you can for loop

```
 for (int i= 0 ; i< order.size();i++){
         ID_list            = order.get(i).get("ID");
         AddressID_list     = order.get(i).get("AddressID");
         PaymentTypeID_list = order.get(i).get("PaymentTypeID");
         CustomerID_list    = order.get(i).get("CustomerID");
}
```

i think you know the rest of the part

i hope that help you